# How can I set firebase adminsdk file in .env file?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

[When I convert my adminSdk text to JSON.stringify and paste it .env file. it gives me that kind of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olC5s.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do something like this.

```
// Admin SDK
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

// use environment variables to initialize the app! 
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    // replace `\` and `n` character pairs w/ single `\n` character
    privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  }),
})
```

In your environment file

```
FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID="[PROJECT_ID]"
FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[KEY_IS_HERE]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL="[CLIENT_EMAIL]"
```